# Setting value of boolean columns based on existence of value in set

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I have a SQL table of the format (INTEGER, json_array(INTEGER)).

I need to return results from the table that have two boolean columns. One is set to true iff a 1 appears in the json_array, and the other true iff a two appears in the array. Obviously there is not mutual exclusion.

For example, if the data were this:

```
-------------------------------
| ID       |   VALUES         |
-------------------------------
|  12      |  [1, 4, 6, 11]   |
_______________________________
|  74      |  [0, 1, 2, 5]    |
-------------------------------
```

I would hope to get back:

```
-------------------------------
| ID       |   HAS1  |  HAS2  |
-------------------------------
|  12      |  true   | false  |
_______________________________
|  74      |  true   | true   | 
-------------------------------
```

I have managed to extract the json data out of the values column using json_each, but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: you can use Count function which will return 0 or more than zero.. 
forexample select Isnull(count(ID),0) from table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, SQLite `max` aggregate function supports boolean, therefore you can simply group by your data:

```
select
    t1.id,
    max(case json_each.value when 1 then true else false end) as has1,
    max(case json_each.value when 2 then true else false end) as has2
from
    yourtable t1,
    json_each(t1.values)
group by
    t1.id
```

Comment: There might be some syntax mistakes, not a json1 expert and did this from memory